# When iam converting a string to JSONObject,Iam getting this error "The constructor JSONObject(String) is undefined"

Tags: java

Here is the code:

```
        String data=request.getParameter("passeddata");
        JSONObject json=new JSONObject(data);
```

Iam using  json_simple-1.1.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use this class : net.sf.json.JSONObject , check which one you're using, this might be your problem